# how to remove punctuation mark in resumeitem but keep the first word bold?

Tags: cv

I have the following lines to generate resume items in my resume.

```
 \resumeItemListStart
      \resumeItem {Calculated} {retention and attrition rates among students participating in Row New York’s athletic and academic programs in Manhattan, Brooklyn, and Queens.}
      \resumeItem {Reviewed} {and cleaned existing records in the organizations SalesForce database using a data de-duplication software}
      \resumeItem{Created}{easy to understand reports and visualizations for monthly operations meetings using the R statistical software}
      \resumeItem {Compiled}{a comprehensive data handbook with information on how to access the organization's data, and the underlying formula’s for calculating various metrics}
            \resumeItemListEnd
```

This gives the following output

[image]

My question is
1. how do I remove the colon ":" punctuation mark after the  first word but still keep the first word bold?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We can be of little help if you don't give more details about what document class you're using and don't show a minimal example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`. There are umpteen resume classes around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you simply use the `itemize` environment? It works very well - just add the following line to the preamble:

```
\def\labelitemi{$\circ$}
```

then, you just have to write like the following

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{ABC} blah blah
    \item \textbf{DEF} blah blah
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Find the following code in your file:

```
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
  \item\small{
    \textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}
```

and delete the `:`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) Instead of deleting the colon in the `\newcommand`, I'd rather suggest using a `\renewcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{\item\small{\textbf{#1}{ #2\vspace{-2pt}}}}` that does exactly the same thing but avoids modifying the class file.